# Given a string, store its substrings in a 2D array

Tags: c

i was asked to write a program, given the string "acmprog", i should generate and ordered set of substrings.

so here's my code:

```
void gen_subStrings(char a[],char sub[][100],int len){
    int i,count=2;
    char first=a[0];
    printf("%c",first);
    for(i=0;i<len-2;i++){
        strncpy(sub[i],a,count);
        printf("%s\n",sub[i]);
        count++;
    }
}

main(){
    char string[]={"acmprog"};

    int len = sizeof(string);
    char subStrings[len][100];

    gen_subStrings(string,subStrings,len);

    system("pause");
}
```

when i run it, the output is like this:

```
 a
```

when it should be:

```
a
ac
acm
acmp
acmpr
acmpro
acmprog
```

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Every time at end of string you have to copy `NULL`

```
 for(i=0;i<len-2;i++)
 {
    strncpy(sub[j],a,count); //Use a different variable
    sub[j][count]='\0';// at end , copy NULL
    printf("%s\n",sub[j++]);
    count++;
 }
```

Comment: i almost forgot the null. no wonder there were extra random characters on my output. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Literal "acmprog"

void gen_subStrings( const char s[], size_t n, char sub[][n] )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i + 1  < n; i++ )
    {
        strncpy( sub[i], s, i + 1 );
        sub[i][i+1] = '\0';
    }

    sub[i][0] = '\0';
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char string[] = "acmprog";
    size_t n = sizeof( string );

    char subStrings[n][n];

    gen_subStrings( string, n, subStrings );



    for( size_t i = 0; subStrings[i][0] != '\0'; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%s\n", subStrings[i] );
    }

    system( "pause" );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
a
ac
acm
acmp
acmpr
acmpro
acmprog
```